# how to send mail using mailchimp in php.i am not sure that using api is correct

Tags: php

how to send mail using mailchimp in php.
I am using api ($url = "https://us8.api.mailchimp.com/1.0/SendEmail";)
it showing "the requested URL /1.0/lists was not found on this server."

Answer (score 0):

Version 1 of the mailchimp api is deprecated and they said it will stop working at the end of 2016. I recommend you look into v3 instead.

I don't know exatly what you mean by "send mail" but you can start a campaign from [this endpoint](http://developer.mailchimp.com/documentation/mailchimp/reference/campaigns/#) (under actions)

Comment: i used v3 but it result is " The requested resource could not be found ".

Comment: It seems to me you are trying to use mailchimp for something it is not. To my knowledge there is not "Send Email" function in mailchimp (api or web). mybt something like [amazon ses](https://aws.amazon.com/ses/) is what you seek?